# VB - The item with the specific name wasn't found

Tags: excel, slicers, vba

I have some VB code in ThisWorkbook that moves slicers up the page when scrolling.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ShF As Shape
Dim ShM As Shape
Dim ShN As Shape
Dim ShO As Shape
Dim SHP As Shape
'specify a slicer
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set ShF = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Segment")
Set ShM = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Promotional Status")
Set ShN = ActiveSheet.Shapes("BNPL Scheme")
Set ShO = ActiveSheet.Shapes("APR")
Set SHP = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Control Group ")

'change position of the slicer
With Windows(1).VisibleRange.Cells(1, 1)
    ShF.Top = .Top + 7
    ShF.Left = .Left + 7
    ShM.Top = .Top + 102
    ShM.Left = .Left + 7
    ShN.Top = .Top + 220
    ShN.Left = .Left + 7
    ShO.Top = .Top + 320
    ShO.Left = .Left + 7
    SHP.Top = .Top + 418
    SHP.Left = .Left + 7
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It works perfectly well when I'm on the sheet the slicers are on but when I go to another tab I get the error 'The item with the specified name wasn't found'. 
I effectively need it just on sheet1 and not the entire workbook.

Comment: Just to be sure (your tags): your app is in vb.net and you access Excel-data?

Comment: They're using `Set` so this is not VB.NET

Comment: Changed. Apologies.

Comment: Could you put the code in the worksheet module, instead of the workbook module? You may be able to change the words `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Segment")` to `sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Segment")`

Comment: Putting it as `Worksheet_SelectionChange`in the code module of Sheet1 will do the trick

Comment: When I change ActiveSheet.Shapes("Segment") to sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Segment") and put it in the worksheet module the slicers stop moving.
When I put the code in Sheet1 and change Workbook_SheetSelectionChange to Worksheet_SelectionChange I get a compile error saying 'Procedure declatation does not match description of event or procedure having the same name.

Comment: Are you carrying the arguments over from `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`? `Worksheet_SelectionChange` will only have `(ByVal Target As Range)` as arguments, whereas `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` has `(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)`. `Worksheet_SelectionChange` doesn't support `ByVal Sh As Object` so carrying over those arguments would cause that error.

Comment: Excellent, thank you Jochen and J. Fox!